# Is it valid to import duplicate named sass partials?

Tags: sass, webpack

I have a React web application, I am using **Webpack 2** for my JS and CSS bundling. The application has the following project structure (simplified for the purposes of this question):

```
src/
-- main.js
-- main.sass
-- Components/
---- SomeComponent/
------ index.js
------ _style.sass
---- AnotherComponent/
------ index.js
------ _style.sass
```

Imagine that I have a lot of components in this app, so the above should simplify the organizational structure.

My `main.sass` file looks like this:

```
@import './**/*'
```

**Question**:

My goal is to grab all those partials named `_style.sass` and import them into my `main.sass` file. Is it possible to do this when all my partials are named the same, meaning they are all named `_style.sass`?

**Bonus Round**:

Feel free to provide how you would configure the webpack.config.js file for this project structure using Webpack 2; I am learning how to bundle and I would love any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually webpack uses the full path to the file as the unique key for file, so you can use same names as much as you want.

You can read here:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-conditions